# Login Control with reCAPTCHA

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, recaptcha

I'm looking to add https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet to an ASP.NET/VB project at the login screen. However, is there a way to track invalid attempts and then increase the time required to login? Or will I need to create my own captcha based system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in the web.config

```
   <configuration>
       <system.web>
          <membership defaultProvider=" ">
            <providers>
              <clear/>
                <add connectionStringName=""
                 applicationName=""
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3 "
                 passwordAttemptWindow="30"
                 name=""
                 type=""/>
               </providers>
              </membership>
         </system.web>
    </configuration>
```